# Extract the upper and lower boundaries from a list (vector) of 2d coordinates

Tags: c++, sorting

My program contains polygons which have the form of a vector containing points (2 dimensional double coordinates, stored in a self-made structure). I'm looking for a quick way of finding the smallest square containing my polygon (ie. knowing the maximal and minimal coordinates of all the points).

Is there a quicker way than just parsing all the points and storing the minimum and maximum values?

Comment: I doubt it, unless you could cache the bounding box and/or compute it iteratively as you build the polygon.

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: You may look at std::minmax_element which is a little better than min_element + max_element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm ou are describing is straightforward: Iterate over all your points and find the minimum and maximum for each coordinate. This is an O(n) algorithm, n being the number of points you have.

You can't do better, since you will need to check at least all your points once, otherwise the last one could be outside the square you found.

Now, the complexity is at best O(n) so you just have to minimize the constant factors, but in that case it's already pretty small : Only one loop over your vector, looking for two maximums and two minimums.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there can be any faster way to find the min & max values in an array of values  than linear time. The only 'optimization' I can think of is to find these values on one of the other occasions you're iterating the array (filling it/performing a function on all points), then perform checks on any data update.

Answer (score 0):

You can either iterate through all points and find max and min values, or do some preprocessing, for example, store your points in treap (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap).
There is no way w/o some preprocessing to do it better than just iterating over all points.